# Is LLDB really the best debugging tool for iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, debugging, lldb

I'm trying to debug my iOS code on device and simulator. Every time i drop to LLDB I find it extremely frustrating to do even basic commands like "print". I find lldb to be poor at resolving return types.

You'd think something like `p myView.bounds.size.height` would just work, but it's actually much more complicated usually, involving casting multiple return types along the chain to finally get the value you're looking for.

Friends who i've watched code seem to just put up with it and spend a lot of time on LLDB semantics. Are there really no better debuggers (or plugins or something?) available?

Comment: At least the current lldb understands property syntax (in many cases). gdb doesn't. - Interestingly, `p myView.layer.bounds.size.height` works, but `p myView.bounds.size.height` does not, so it might be worth to submit a bug report.

Comment: It's that the return type of properties is more explicit than the return type of methods, especially when dealing with dot-syntax.  LLDB has to resolve dot-access to a method call, and in turn, loses some measure of safety (whereas if you use brackets it most always gets it right).  Also, some of those dots have to be resolved to struct member access instead of method calls, which can be ambiguous depending on how much information the compiler strips from structs

Comment: i just took up a very defensive (say, 'assertive') written style over years of frustration debugging on OS X and later iOS. tons of assertions, unit testing and really strict semantics. some programmers dislike that degree of checking, but there's not much else you can do to diagnose errors when the programs and dependencies become complex in this situation.

Comment: I would love it if someone posted a real alternative. However, I'm pretty sure the answer is yes, lldb is slightly better than gdb, but still sucks. I sometimes go so far as to break commands into one call at a time, and take the pointer returned to use in the next command. Something like: (NSString *)[(SomeObject *)0x034ffd87 someMethod]. That sucks.

Comment: As @escrafford said, yes, lldb is slightly better than gdb, but still sucks. File Apple bugreports as often as you are able to on specific behaviors that get in your way.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind about lldb is that it uses llvm to parse and compile your expressions -- it has the full power of a compiler at its disposal.  But that also means it has the syntactic strictness of a compiler, but without any of the system header files (prototypes, class interface definitions).  There are many instances where llvm is parsing the expression with relaxed semantics to allow things to "just work", and lldb tries to get information from the Objective-C runtime to fill out its knowledge.  But it's a tricky environment to operate in.